# Regex match selecting 1 character too much

Tags: c#, regex

So I want to format a file of strings which can span over multiple lines and are seperated by empty lines. The result should have every string in one line and remove the empty lines.

After some fiddeling I found this regex to be what I was searching for `(\n)(?:[^\n])` but then I noticed that it also selects the first character from the next line which is bad.

Example lines:

```
Run in circles, yell and shout.

When men are easy in their circumstances, they are naturally enemies
to innovation.

When smashing monuments, always save the pedestals - they come in
handy.

When the hounds bay, the fox and the rabbit are brothers.

When the mouse laughs at the cat, there is a hole very near by.
```

First character of new line beeing selected:
[image: First character of new line being selected]

UPDATE:
I found `"\\r\\n(?!\\r\\n)"` as a Working regex . . . at least on the surface but in C# it just doesnt do anything but i used an online tool and it worked there? Its quite a long file so maybe thats the problem
The Method im using: `Regex.Replace(txt, "\\r\\n(?!\\r\\n)", "");`

Comment: Do you mean you need `\n(?!\n)`?

Comment: Ruby has a nice method for this: `str.squeeze("\n")`.

Comment: Try `Regex.Replace(txt, @"\r?\n(?!\r?\n)", "")` if there can be LF only line endings. Best is to provide some **literal text**, or a **string literal** for testing. Images are never suitable for regex debugging.

Comment: i did provide text for testing right above the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look for the pattern `(not \n)\n(not \n)` with captures and then replace with the captured characters with a space between them.

This regex does just that:

```
([^\n])\n([^\n])
```

The replace expression varies with the particular language. In JavaScript and PHP use `$1 $2`. In Python use `\1 \2`

See [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/gyLfX4/1) in action at Regex101

Comment: this one matches a letter before and after the \n wich i dont want  ... also i found the problem wich i marked at the end of my question
i now have the problem with the Regex.replace not working

Answer (score 0):

Will this work? Note you'll want to expand the code snippet as the console debug will wrap lines.

```js
let str = `Run in circles, yell and shout.

When men are easy in their circumstances, they are naturally enemies
to innovation.

When smashing monuments, always save the pedestals - they come in
handy.

When the hounds bay, the fox and the rabbit are brothers.

When the mouse laughs at the cat, there is a hole very near by.`;

let re = /([^\n])\n([^\n])/g;

console.log(str.replace(re, '$1 $2'));
```

Comment: I updated the original post The problem seemed to be that im not escaping the \ in \n

Answer (score 0):

you can replace 2 sequential new line character with one of them!

```
(\n)\n
```

replace with first matching group `$1`

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/q7KSJN/1)

```js
var text = `Run in circles, yell and shout.

When men are easy in their circumstances, they are naturally enemies
to innovation.

When smashing monuments, always save the pedestals - they come in
handy.

When the hounds bay, the fox and the rabbit are brothers.

When the mouse laughs at the cat, there is a hole very near by.`;

var res = text.replace(/(\n)\n/gm, "$1");

console.log(res);
```

Comment: I updated the original post The problem seemed to be that im not escaping the \ in \n

Answer (score 0):

Replace 1 or more  whitespace characters (which includes all flavours of  newline chars) with a space:

```
Search: '\s+'
Replace: ' '
```

Using the language/tool of your choice.

Comment: I found this before but i dont want to remove every whitespace character if i would  everything would be in one line

Comment: Oh, I misread *have every string in one line* in the question as you waning "all strings to end up in big one line".